# Not able to install pig version 0.17.0 ; error : Cannot locate pig-core-h2.jar. do 'ant jar', and try again

Tags: hadoop, ant, installation, bigdata, apache-pig

While installing pig version 0.17.0 on my ubuntu system i am facing an error after i run a command pig -help , it throws an error : Cannot locate pig-core-h2.jar. do 'ant jar', and try again

input command : pig -help

output : Cannot locate pig-core-h2.jar. do 'ant jar', and try again

pig version - 0.17.0

i have already configured the .bashrc file with all the given variables.

```
export PIG_HOME=/usr/local/pig-0.17.0
export PATH=$PIG_HOME/bin:$HADOOP_HOME/bin:$PATH
export PIG_CLASSPATH=$HADOOP_HOME/conf
```

Answer (score 0):

Does $PIG_HOME/pig-0.17.0-core-h2.jar (/usr/local/pig-0.17.0/pig-0.17.0-core-h2.jar) exist in your environment?

If not, I would reinstall from the tarball.

Comment: Thanks alot for the information, i was having some errors with JAVA HOME in bashrc file, i fixed that and got it rectified .